# How to convert a JSON string in JS date object?

Tags: javascript, json

```
   {"date":"Thu Dec 06 14:56:01 IST 2012"}
```

I am getting this string as JSON can I convert it to JS date object?

Comment: @ADC I have no idea how this is related to the question.

Comment: @DeepakKaithwas This kind of date format might be a bit difficult to parse. Why would server send such date format? Can you change it to ISO string for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Unfortunately i was totally wrong, sry for that,my bad, it happened to always result in today,
but to not screw you up, heres an solution which should work for you anyway
If you get Different Time strings from your Server, maybe the best way is to write a Regex pattern that matches your String patterns

- Access your `date` propertie from your JSON Object
- Since instantiating a Date object with this "Thu Dec 06 14:56:01 IST 2012" String would result in an Invalid Date
- Remove the "IST" `myJson.date.replace(" IST","")`
- Instantiate the your Date object with your new String `myDate = new Date("Thu Dec 06 14:56:01 2012")`
- Now theres really your Date Object

---

```
var myJson = {"date":"Thu Dec 06 14:56:01 IST 2012"}
var myDate = new Date(myJson.date.replace(" IST",""))
console.log(myDate.toLocaleDateString())
```

Heres the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/inusun/1/edit)

Comment: Oh, it does actually work under Chrome ( missed the inner `Date` call ). Very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to convert your JSON to the data object it's parsing this date as a string.

```
var myJson = {"date":"Thu Dec 06 14:56:01 IST 2013"}
var myDate = new Date(Date(myJson.date))
console.log(myDate.getFullYear()) // 2012
```

Doesn't work with a Year different from the current one.

Related link
[Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)